# PHP array as JSON response for jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a search form where I want to display suggestions via jQuery autocomplete when 3 characters are typed. The suggestions are drawn from a mySQL DB. 
What happens: jQuery does successfully transmit the typed chars to the PHP file, where they successfully get embedded in an mySQL query. 
When I open the PHP file separately with an assumed search term, f.e. like this: `/soplogsearch.php?term=xyz` it works perfectly and I see the aimed at result of `echo json_encode($return_arr);` 
but back on the HTML search form file autocomplete doesn't suggest a thing. I have no errors in the console. I tried to echo the json_encode elsewhere on the HTML file and its output was `Null`.

I have made a fiddle for the (very simple) Javascript/jQuery and HTML set up: https://jsfiddle.net/9bf6s07f/1/

the relevant PHP code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['term']))
    {
    $term = $_GET['term'];
    $termwild = "%$term%";
    $return_arr = array();
    $service = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT service FROM master WHERE service LIKE \"" . $termwild . "\"");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($service))
        {
        $return_arr[] = $data[0];
        }
    json_encode($return_arr);
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
    }
```

EDIT: For quicker access I'm including the HTML and jQuery parts of the code here instead of link you to the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9bf6s07f

```
<body>
     <label>Service:</label>
     <input type='text' name='' value='' class='auto'>
</body>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
      source: "soplogsave.php",
      minLength: 3
    });
  });
});
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? I tested autocomplete separately with a set of javascript variables and it worked fine.

EDIT 2: Because all of the comments seem to imply my PHP is wrong and I'd have an error in the console, I made a screenshot from the network tab of the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkP3M.png

Comment: I dont think your query is correct. Try this:
 `$service = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT service FROM master WHERE service LIKE '%{$term}%'");`
I am doing a similar thing in my app as you are attempting to do.

Comment: Is your PHP file returns results?

Comment: but this query does seem to works! I can echo it perfectly fine with mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Just to say - `mysql_*` is **deprecated** and you should be using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @HJerem yes! I can display the desired results of json_encode($return_arr) perfectly on the php file, i just can't "bring" them back to the autocomplete of the html search form

Comment: check the server response in the "network" tab of the browser console and check if there is no php warning or notice avoiding the parsing of the JSON answer.

Comment: there is none. As i already wrote, the PHP **WORKS** i get the full desired array from the dynamically typed in search form when I check the php file via the network tab of firebug!! but it does not get send back to the seach form as autocomplete!!

Comment: @n00dl3 I made a screenshot from the network tab of the browser console that displays the desired array, the PHP seeming to be without flaw.. http://i.imgur.com/i6nAQ98.png 
This is so frustrating, I try to make this work since days :(

Comment: you should return ONLY json

Comment: JqueryUI says: "When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a **URL resource that will return JSON data**"

Comment: @n00dl3 Thank you so much for the answer! But do you mean I can't have anything else on the php output except the query and the json data? How do I return JSON only?

Comment: only json data, you should not echo any HTML, just make your DB work behind the scene then `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and then: `echo json_encode($return_arr);`. There's no magic, jQuery (neither any framework) cannot know that you've hidden some json in a random HTML file.

Comment: You can use another php file, or route, depending on your project. nothing BUT json.
Bye ;-).

Comment: @n00dl3 THANK YOU SO MUCH, that was it!!! Now that you said it (that frameworks cannot know that I've hidden some json), it sounds very reasonable :D Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have achieved it in my code:

**PHP**

```
$param = $_GET["term"];

$stk_adddep = "
SELECT * FROM stocktake_products WHERE stocktake_id = '{$stocktake_id}' AND is_deli = 0 AND (product_code LIKE '%{$param}%' OR product_name LIKE '%{$param}%'); ";

//FB::info($stk_adddep);
//echo $stk_adddep;
//die();
$result = db::c()->query($stk_adddep);
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['itemCode']  = $row['product_code'];
    $row_array['itemDesc']  = $row['product_name'];
    //$row_array['itemPrice'] = $row['unit_cost_price'];

    array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
}

/* Free connection resources. */
//mysql_close($conn);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

And then javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Use the .autocomplete() method to compile the list based on input from user
var url10 = '<?php echo Navigation::gUrl('/users/admin/stocktake_details_cocktails.php', array('stocktake_id' => $stocktake_id, 'action' => 'find_products'));?>';

$('#itemCode').autocomplete({
    source: url10,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');
                // Populate the input fields from the returned values
                $itemrow.find('#itemCode').val(ui.item.itemCode);
                $itemrow.find('#itemDesc').val(ui.item.itemDesc);
                //$itemrow.find('#itemPrice').val(ui.item.itemPrice);

                // Give focus to the next input field to recieve input from user
                $('#itemQty').focus();

        return false;
    }
// Format the list menu output of the autocomplete
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.itemCode + " - " + item.itemDesc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

See if you can maybe apply this to your code?

Comment: Thank you but this is far too extensive for my simple code :( I'm not that literate in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The answer was posted in the comments by user @n00dl3.